# Json Serializer Scala

Tags: json, scala

I want to serialize a map to Json.

```
val b1 = List("aa", "bb")
val b2 = List("cc", "dd")
```

I want to call toJson and print the map {b1:["aa","bb"], b2:["cc","dd"]}

```
val c2 = Map("b1" -> b1, "b2" -> b2)
println(c2.toJson)
```

I try to implement like this :

```
trait JsonSerializer[T]:
    def serialize(obj: T): String
    extension (x: T)
      def toJson: String = serialize(x)



def indentTail(value: String): String =
  val lines = value.split("\n").toList
  (lines.head :: lines.tail.map(x => s"  $x")).mkString("\n")

    object Maptostring:
  given maptostring :JsonSerializer[Map[String,List[String]] with
   def serialize(maps:Map[String,List[String]] ) =
     val lines = for entry <- maps yield
       val value = summon[JsonSerializer[T]].toJson(entry)
       s"- ${indentTail(value)}"
  lines.mkString("\n")
```

I change my code. I want to do something like the above but again it failed.
And then print toJson

Answer (score 2):

You put unnecessary `Map[String,List[String]]` which confused the compiler and made it think that it was anonymous `given`. Just remove it and it will compile:

```
trait JsonSerializer[T]:
  def serialize(obj: T): String
  extension (x: T)
    def toJson: String = serialize(x)

object Maptostring:
  given maptostring : JsonSerializer[Map[String,List[String]]] = ???
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I change my code a bit, any chance you can help me finish the implementation?